# how to find the first number from string in js(javascript)?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, expression

How to find the first number from string in javascript?

```
var string = "120-250";
var string = "120,250";
var string = "120 | 250";
```

Comment: regular expression, match start of string and numbers

Comment: Just use `parseInt(string)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that may help you understand.

Use the `search()` method to get the index of the first number in the string.

The search method takes a regular expression and returns the index of the first match in the string.

```
const str = 'one 2 three 4'

const index = str.search(/[0-9]/);
console.log(index); // 4

const firstNum = Number(str[index]);
console.log(firstNum); // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic regular expression start of string followed by numbers [`/^\d+/`](https://regexper.com/#%2F%5E%5Cd%2B%2F)

```js
const getStart = str => str.match(/^\d+/)?.[0];

console.log(getStart("123,456"));
console.log(getStart("123-456"));
console.log(getStart("123|456"));
console.log(getStart("xxx,xxx"));
```

Or parseInt can be used, but it will drop leading zeros.

```js
const getStart = str => parseInt(str, 10);

console.log(getStart("123,456"));
console.log(getStart("123-456"));
console.log(getStart("123|456"));
console.log(getStart("xxx,xxx"));
```